# Mathematica makes no sound under Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, java

After waiting for days for my license I now got the opportunity to install *Wolfram Mathematica 8* at home. However, neither the `Play` nor the `Speak` functions are doing anything as it seems that Mathematica cannot produce any sound output due to unknown reasons. Might anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Does the Mathematica documentation say anything about sound? If there's a configuration somewhere where `pulseaudio` is a possible setting, select it.

Comment: @Gilles: I found a "solution" [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mathematica#Sound) however apt doesn't know the arts package. Any idea how to install it?

Comment: Mathematica tries to use OSS, while most linux dists use ALSA. See [No sound in Mathematica 8.0.1 under Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/295979/no-sound-in-mathematica-8-0-1-under-linux)

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu uses the [PulseAudio](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio) sound system. It comes with the `paplay` command to play a sound file. The approach you found [on the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mathematica#Sound) should work, but you need to use `paplay` (or some other equivalent program) rather than the now obsolete aRts.

Here's some code adapted from [the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mathematica#Sound). Add it to your `~/.Mathematica/Kernel/init.m` or to a file that it includes. In addition to running `paplay` rather than `artsplay`, I've changed it to pipe the data rather than store it in a temporary file. Untested.

```
Begin["System`Private`"]
Unprotect[$SoundDisplayFunction]
Clear[$SoundDisplayFunction]
$SoundDisplayFunction =
    Module[{stream},
      stream = OpenWrite["!pacat", BinaryFormat -> True];
      BinaryWrite[stream, ExportString[#1, "WAV"]];
      Close[stream];
    ] &
Protect[$SoundDisplayFunction]
End[];
```

See also [No sound in Mathematica 8.0.1 under Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/295979/no-sound-in-mathematica-8-0-1-under-linux), which reports that a similar approach worked in Mathematica 8 (with ALSA rather than PulseAudio).

Comment: +1; Although to get it working I had to replace `OpenWrite["!paplay"]` with `OpenWrite["!pacat",BinaryFormat -> True]`. Also, you get the normal graphics output if you append a `#1` to the end of your `$SoundDisplayFunction`. Finally, I've updated [my answer](http://superuser.com/questions/295979/no-sound-in-mathematica-8-0-1-under-linux/295980#295980) to further discuss OSS (which Mathematica wants to use) versus ALSA/PA (that Ubuntu uses).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that that version of Mathematica using OSS and that your Ubuntu using ALSA.

Add the following 'sound.m' script to `~/.Mathematica/Kernel`:

```
(* ::Package:: *)

(*
  * Set up a $SoundDisplayFunction for the
  * Linux version of Mathematica and potentially other unixes, too.
  *)

Begin["System`Private`"]

Unprotect[$SoundDisplayFunction]
Clear[$SoundDisplayFunction]

$SoundDisplayFunction :=
     Module[{playCmd,soundFileName},
            Export[$SoundDisplay, #1];
         (* is there a way to get the sample rate, etc. from the audio 
stream? *)
         playCmd = "/usr/bin/play";
         soundFileName = "/tmp/" <> ToString[Unique["sound"]] <> ".wav";
         playCmd = playCmd <> " " <> soundFileName;

         Export[soundFileName, #1, "WAV"];
         Run[playCmd];
         Run["/bin/rm -f " <> soundFileName];
        ] &

Protect[$SoundDisplayFunction]

End[];

(********************CODE ENDS***************************)

After creating 'sound.m', add the following line
to ~/.Mathematica/Kernel/init.m :

Get["sound.m"];
```

Restart Mathematica to reload the kernel.

Comment: I get a "Set::wrsym: Symbol $SoundDisplayFunction is Protected." error when starting Mathematica 6.0.2.1. Also, I assume everything after "CODE ENDS" should not be in sound.m, right? thanks

Comment: Also, when playing sounds in Mathematica, I get this error (although I hear the sound): «Export::infer: "Cannot infer format of file \!\(\"stdout\"\)."» thanks

Comment: Also, is there a similar fix as this for CDF Player?

Comment: Also, this solution doesn't seem to work with other functions like FrequencyModulation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After upgrading to Mathematica 10, sound generation works on Linux.